# How to prevent false trigger to PIC chip input

Tags: pic, noise

I am trying to use an off the shelf battery operated device in a larger project.  The device was powered from 4 AA batteries which I've replace with a +5V power source. The device uses a 16F505 PIC chip and it's operating range is 2.2V to 5.5V. 
[PIC Spec Sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41236E.pdf)

I have replaced the start button with a simple relay contact closure, externally controlled. The device's Start input is tied to Vcc with an EXTERNAL 20K pull-up resistor. The Start button shorts the pin to ground to start the action. In testing, when I simply place a test probe on the power input the device also starts on its own. Also, I simply touch the pad leading to the Start with a test lead (without shorting to ground) and the unit will start.  I tried adding a 1000uF cap at the device power input that didn't seem to reduce the "spontaneous starts".  I don't think I can increase the pull-up resistor value as the spec sheet says for 5.5V typical is 21K and max is 23K. I think a filter on the power input would help but I'm unsure and also unsure how to spec one. Can someone advise on selecting one and perhaps offer additional tips or possible solutions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The spec for pull-up resistor is the internal pull-ups, it has nothing to do with the external resistor. You can easily make it lower (e.g. 10k) without issue.

Comment: Ah. Ok.  However there IS an actual external 20K resistor on the device pcb connected to each of the input lines.

Comment: What _exactly_ is your +5V power source?

Comment: +5V Power is a TDK DSP10-05 power supply. http://us.tdk-lambda.com/ftp/appnotes/dsp10_userguide.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I would think it is safe to decrease the pullup value from 20k. for example, connect 1k in parallel.

You mention a spec sheet, but do not say, which one.
It may be the PIC and a value of 20k for an on-chip pullup makes sense.
Still, an external pullup can always be added.

The pullup value is usually not critical.
You only need to ensure that whatever device pulling the line to ground can handle the current.
And that your power envelope can handle it: in battery operated devices we always try to mak all currents as slow as possible.
But in a mains powered device, a 5mA current for the input is probably acceptable.
And your relay contact should easily be able to handle 5mA (5V/1kOhms) instead of the 250 µA you are using now (5V/20k).

You touching the input with a test lead is interpreted as "low"?
This can happen: your test lead (and your body) is an antenna and will pick up all kinds of signals. This will lead to a voltage fed into the input pin.
This could actually overcome the level set by the 20k pullup - although that sounds a bit fishy. I'd guess there was no pullup active at the time when you saw this effect.

Adding a 100nF capacitator to the input is probably also a good idea.
That will eliminate a lot of nasty high-frequency noise picked up by all the leads.
In principle, this will also slow down your inputs response to the external signal (the cap needs to charge up via the pullup before the input is registering as high again), but this will not be a problem in your application: compared to a manual process like "button pressing" the charging process is quick.
But keep it in mind for your next project where you want to de-noise a fast-changing signal. :-)

When reading a relay (or other mechanical contact like a pushbutton) you always need to debounce the signal: the contact will neither close or open instantaniously. It will behave like a rubber ball falling to the floor: it bounces up, falls down again, up again etc. until it finally comes to rest.

Typical bounce times are between 5 to 30 milliseconds in my experience.
Since the code on your Pic is already evaluating a manual pushbutton, chances are good that the relay contact will work right away: if the buttons and relay bounce times are similar, the debouncing routine will already handle it.
If the relay bounce is longer than the debouncing routine compensates for, you need to change the code or find a relay that bounces less.
In my experience, Reed relays show much shorter bounce than mechanicals, at least on average.

Hope this helps
hase

Answer (score 1):

You need a small capacitor in the circuit to create a time-constant. Use a 0.1uF 25 volt ceramic capacitor across the switch lines as close to the PIC IC as possible. The PIC inputs are very high impedance and without dampening will pick up any noise source, causing false triggers.

You can also lower your pull-up resistor to 2.2K to drop the sensitivity of the input by effectively lowering the input impedance to 2.2K. That and a filter capacitor should cut way down on false triggers. The capacitor could be as high as 1uF. If it is very high (>10uF) the discharge current will slowly burn out the switch contacts.

If your good with code you can also implement a simple 2 or 4 pole digital filter (Takes 3 bytes. One to count up if switch is closed, one to count up if switch is open, another to store the true/false results).

The following assembler code is part of what I used to filter switch and relay contact inputs. I could not extract the main code as it is embedded in many places in 13,000 lines of code. Read what I have inserted as it details the procedures for implementing the filter. The code is from 2001, so it would not work on todays Microchip MPU's. I cannot even load my old MPLAB into Windows 7, it gets rejected.

**DIGITAL FILTER:**
 INPUT PIN IS READ AT A 1KHZ OR 100 HZ RATE. IF PIN IS HIGH 'INPUT_FIL_H' COUNTS UP BY ONE AND 'INP_FIL_L' IS CLEARED TO ZERO.

IF 'INPUT_FIL_H' REACH'S 'MAX_CNT_A' THEN 'INP_FIL_STA' BIT 0 IS SET HIGH AND BIT 1 IS SET LOW AND 'INPUT_FIL_H' COUNT VALUE IS HELD.

IF PIN IS LOW 'INPUT_FIL_L' COUNTS UP BY ONE AND 'INP_FIL_H' IS CLEARED TO ZERO. IF 'INPUT_FIL_L' REACH'S 'MAX_CNT_A' THEN-'INP_FIL_STA' BIT 1 IS SET HIGH AND BIT 0 IS SET LOW AND 'INPUT_FIL_L' COUNT VALUE IS HELD.

IF SAMPLE RATE IS OTHER THAN 1KHZ OR 100HZ THEN 'MAX_CNT_A/B' MUST BE ADJUSTED TO GET SAME TIME DELAY. ADJUST 'MAX_CNT_A/B' BY DOUBLING VALUES.I.E. PIN MUST MAINTAIN STATE FOR 80mS TO BE ACCEPTED AS BEING HIGH OR LOW. AT 4 TIMES THEIR VALUE IT TAKES 160mS TO BE ACCEPTED AS BEING HIGH OR LOW.

THE NEXT BLOCK OF USER CODE READS THE HIGH/LOW BITS OF THE 'INP_FIL_STA' REGISTER TO DETERMINE NEXT ACTION.

**RESERVE RAM FOR FILTER:**
 
RES BYTE   INP_FIL_STA
 RES BYTE   INP_FIL_H 
RES BYTE  INP_FIL_L

**INITIALIZE VALUES:** 
HIGH         EQU     0x01 
LOW       EQU     0x00 
ZERO         EQU     0x00 
FULL         EQU     0xFF 
BIT_0 EQU     0x00              ;BIT '0' OF INP_FIL_STATUS REGISTER (RAM)
 BIT_1        EQU     0x01              ;BIT '1' OF INP_FIL_STATUS REGISTER (RAM)
 MAX_CNT_A    EQU     0x28              ;EQUALS 40mS IF SAMPLE RATE IS 1KHZ, 40 CONTINUOUS SAMPLES MUST BE TRUE OR FALSE 
MAX_CNT_B    EQU     0x04 ;EQUALS 40mS IF SAMPLE RATE IS 100HZ, 4 CONTINUOUS SAMPLES MUST BE TRUE OR FALSE
INP_FIL_STA  EQU     0x00              ;INPUT FILTER STATUS. ONLY FIRST 2 BITS ARE USED. 
INP_FIL_H    EQU     0x00              ;COUNTS UP IF INPUT IS HIGH
 INP_FIL_L    EQU     0x00              ;COUNTS UP IF INPUT IS LOW

Comment: "Across the switch lines".  Do you mean from the input to Vcc or from input to Ground?

Comment: From switch input to ground. Also reduce the value of the pull-up resistor as much as practical.

Comment: can you tell me more about the digital filter, I have another application that might use it. Do you have a link to some basic code? Thanks!

Comment: I do not have a link as I created the code myself using MPLAB assembler. When I have a chance I will append it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Schmitt trigger inverter to the input and change your PIC to check for a logic LO instead of logic HI. The [SN74HC14](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc14.pdf) Schmitt Trigger inverter provides the Boolean function Y = !A and quote:

`Schmitt-trigger inputs are designed to provide a minimum separation between positive and negative switching thresholds. This allows for noisy or slow inputs that would cause problems such as oscillation or excessive current draw with normal CMOS inputs.`

Adding capacitors to debounce is not an ideal solution, whereas a Schmitt trigger is designed for exactly that. Hope you find this useful.

Comment: You have to use a capacitor at the input of Schmitt trigger as well.